# Xamarin - System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, xamarin

I've a problem that occurs randomly.

[mono] Unhandled Exception:
[mono] System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
[mono-rt] [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.

But, if I control the indicated line, the code write here is

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => 
                    {
                Debug.WriteLine("aaa5");
                    AppViewModel.Instance.CpvVisibility = false;
                    Bottom.IsVisible = false;
                    FattureListView.IsVisible = false;
```

});

Someone with the same problem? 
Thanks.

Comment: What platform is throwing that error? And what is the full exception/stacktrace?

Comment: The platform is Android. The full stacktrace don't give me any informations, only the number line(that is Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread).